# What does it mean by client in the software design patterns?

Tags: php, design-patterns, client-server, client

What does it mean by **client** in the software design patterns? For instance I see this word has been mentioned a lot in design patterns, such as in [this PHP Visitor Design Pattern tutorial](http://www.php5dp.com/). It even has a **class** called **Client** (is it a design pattern as well?)

```
//Client.php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
// Autoload given function name.
function includeAll($className)
{
    include_once($className . '.php');
}
//Register
spl_autoload_register('includeAll');

class Client
{
    private static $shapeElement;
    private static $color;
    private static $package;

    //client request
    public static function request()
    {
      self::$shapeElement= array();
      self::$shapeElement=$_POST['shape'];
      self::$color=$_POST['color'];
      self::$package= array();

      $obStructure = new ObjectStructure();
      $colorVisitor= new self::$color();

      //Attach concrete elements to array & accept visitor
      foreach (self::$shapeElement as $shapeNow)
      {
        $obStructure->attach(new $shapeNow,$colorVisitor);
      }

      //Display selected shapes
      self::$package=$obStructure->getElements();
      foreach (self::$package as $colorShape)
      {
        echo $colorShape->showShape();
      }
    } 
}
Client::request();
```

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_(computing)), the **client** in client–server networks, which is what I usually understand it as,

> A client is a piece of computer hardware or software that accesses a
>   service made available by a server. The server is often (but not
>   always) on another computer system, in which case the client accesses
>   the service by way of a network. The term applies to programs or
>   devices that are part of a client–server model.

Is this then the definition for **client** in the software design patterns as well?

If the **client** is made into a class,

```
class Client
{
    ... 
}
```

then, can I have **many** clients as well and where should I keep these clients in MVC architectural pattern? Should/ can I create a directory called **client** and keep all client classes in it?

Answer (score 2):

The client is the 'code' that will be executed in the client machine. However, if we are talking about web applications, the client is probably the browser. So, no back-end code (e.g. PHP) will be executed in the client. There are also occasions, where the client machine is not a browser, for example the occasion of ATMs functionality. On this occasion, the client code is the one that will be executed in the ATM machine when a specific transaction is made by the end user (withdrawal, deposit etc.).

Now, regarding the 'many clients', it depends if you refer to different instances or types. If you refer to different types of clients (e.g. different client for each company's ATM), then you can make an generic Client class and create one class for each company that will inherit the basic functionality from the generic class. If you are referring to instances, then you do not have to do anything, since when a new transaction is to be made by a client machine, a new instance of the suitable Client class will be initialised and this one will be used. You can just create a class understanding the type of the client machine and initializing the suitable kind of Client.

It would be wise to create a different directory for the Client class and a separate sub-directory for all the different sub-classes that inherit.

Comment: thanks for the answer. `The client is the 'code' that will be executed in the client machine.` but the `class Client` in the example above I have is a php and php is a server side scripting, isn't?

Comment: Sure, PHP is server side. This is the reason I made the distinction with the 2 examples. Your example can be implemented, in projects where the client machine can execute PHP, such as ATMs supporting PHP :P . However, it is not feasible in web applications (web sites etc.), since you will have to implement the desired functionality in Javascript or any other client-side language that is supported by browsers.

Comment: aww ok thanks for the reply. it seems quite hard to distinquish but i guess I can understand what you are trying to explain. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The client is the generic name for a class or classes that normally benefit from the pattern. In real applications, it's probably not called Client.

Many patterns provide [protected variations](http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/protectedVariation.pdf) and the Client is the class that is protected from variations in the part of the design that is open to extension. In the case of `Visitor`, the code in Client should not require any (or many) changes if you add a new Visitor functionality.

Another way to look at it is that programming is done for two reasons:

1. developing applications
2. developing frameworks (or code to facilitate developing applications -- the first reason)

Design patterns fall into the second aspect. In this case, think of design patterns as having a *Client* programmer, whose goal is developing applications quickly and easily. Any of the classes in the code she develops could be the *client* classes, particularly if they use the patterns.